# How to do parametrized record range query in surrealdb?

Tags: surrealdb

This is what I want to achieve:

```
dg/test> create item:ulid() set index = 1;
[
    {
        id: item:01HGE6SJM83WQYAWE2DZJV389D,
        index: 1
    }
]

dg/test> create item:ulid() set index = 12
[
    {
        id: item:01HGE6SKP0YM6X1PT0QTSKW6PD,
        index: 12
    }
]

dg/test> create item:ulid() set index = 22;
[
    {
        id: item:01HGE6SPXM4Y7007SP7XX1Q0CK,
        index: 22
    }
]

dg/test> select * from item:01HGE6SKP0YM6X1PT0QTSKW6PD..;
[
    {
        id: item:01HGE6SKP0YM6X1PT0QTSKW6PD,
        index: 12
    },
    {
        id: item:01HGE6SPXM4Y7007SP7XX1Q0CK,
        index: 22
    }
]

dg/test> let $seq="01HGE6SKP0YM6X1PT0QTSKW6PD";
[]
dg/test> select * from item:$seq; --< Parse error: Failed to parse query at line 1 column 19 expected one of WITH, WHERE, SPLIT, GROUP, ORDER, LIMIT, START, FETCH, VERSION, TIMEOUT, PARELLEL, or EXPLAIN
  |
1 | select * from item:$seq;
```

As you can see I cannot use `$seq` like this way.

I also tried using `type::thing` but I don't know how to use it with range ("..")

```
dg/test> select * from type::thing("item", $seq);
[
    {
        id: item:01HGE6SKP0YM6X1PT0QTSKW6PD,
        index: 12
    }
]

dg/test> select * from type::thing("item", $seq)..; --< Parse error: Failed to parse query at line 1 column 41 expected an identifier
  |
1 | select * from type::thing("item", $seq)..;
  |                                        ^
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Maybe I should use a simple `WHERE id > $seq`. However range queries are very efficient and I'm not sure about the `WHERE` clause performance in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug, as what you wrote here would otherwise be the correct approach.
`select * from type::thing("item", $seq)..`

Would it be possible for you open this as bug in our repo?
https://github.com/surrealdb/surrealdb/issues

Comment: Done: https://github.com/surrealdb/surrealdb/issues/3650